# Pandas coarsen categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

Let's say I have a categorical variable with the following values, given by calling `unique()` on the column in the dataframe:

`Categories (7, object): [0-2, 6-8, 9-11, 3-5, 15-17, 12-14, 24-26]`

and that I have the following occurrences for each of these categories given by calling `value_counts()`:

`0-2      209
3-5       34
6-8       17
9-11       7
15-17      6
12-14      3
24-26      1`

what would be a good way to coarsen/compress these categories into two new categories "high" and "low"?

Answer (score 0):

This is using `pd.cut` with the right value of the range, and cut them into two , also you can using `qcut` to get different cut result

```
groupkey=pd.cut(s.index.str.split('-').str[-1].astype(int),2,labels=['low','high'])
s.groupby(groupkey).sum()
low     270
high      7
Name: v, dtype: int64
```